# Simple Add To Cart Ajax Button

Tags: customization

I need the simple add to cart ajax button on my image how can I achieve this thanks. Website reesh.co.za. Please as I need to implement it on the website. I'm using the astra theme

Comment: Can you provide a list of plugins you are using? Is your eCommerce platform WooCommerce or another plugin? *Edit* Just saw your site and you seem to be using WooCommerce.

Comment: Thanks yes it's woocommerce,here is the list of plugins below:

Comment: Advanced Order Export For WooCommerce
 Advanced Woo Search
 Astra Bulk Edit
 Astra Customizer Reset
 Astra Pro
 Astra Starter Sites
 Astra Widgets
 bidorbuy Store Integrator
 Blog2Social: Social Media Auto Post & Scheduler
 CartFlows
 Classic Editor
 Click to Chat
 Count Per Day
 Custom Adobe Fonts (Typekit)
 Custom Fonts
 Customizer Search
 Elementor
 Elementor - Header, Footer & Blocks
 Enable Media Replace
 Facebook for WooCommerce
 Google Analytics for WordPress by MonsterInsights
 Gutenberg

Comment: Import / Export Customizer Settings
 JetBlog For Elementor
 JetElements For Elementor
 JetEngine
 Jetpack by WordPress.com
 JetPopup
 JetSmartFilters
 JetTabs For Elementor
 JetTricks
 JetWooBuilder For Elementor
 JivoChat
 Mailchimp for WooCommerce
 Premium Addons for Elementor
 Raven
 Really Simple SSL
 Regenerate Thumbnails
 Schema - All In One Schema Rich Snippets
 ShoppingFeeder
 Sidebar Manager
 Smush
 Social Media and Share Icons (Ultimate Social Media)
 SSL Insecure Content Fixer
 Stock Sync for WooCommerce

Comment: String Locator
 Ultimate Addons for Gutenberg
 UpdraftPlus - Backup/Restore
 WooCommerce
 WooCommerce - Store Exporter Deluxe
 WooCommerce Admin
 WooCommerce Advanced Free Shipping
 WooCommerce Blocks
 WooCommerce Cart
 WooCommerce Cart Abandonment Recovery
 WooCommerce PayFast Gateway
 WooCommerce POS
 WooCommerce Shipment Tracking
 Wordfence Security
 WP Encrypt
 WP File Manager
 WPForms Lite
 WP Hide & Security Enhancer
 WunderWP
 YITH WooCommerce Wishlist
 Yoast SEO
 Zapper Payments for WooCommerce

Comment: Sorry there was no way to upload a picture

Comment: Can you link me to the page you are trying to add an Add to Cart button?

Comment: the link is https://reesh.co.za/product-category/shop/ the ajax add to cart is supposed to be on the image and not the button below the image